# Cheese Webcam Booth stuck in fullscreen

Tags: cheese

I decided to put Cheese Webcam Booth in fullscreen mode.  How do I undo this?

Comment: Pressing F11 doesn't work?

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot... Thanks XD, it worked

Comment: If it worked, then don't forget to accept it as the answer below by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can press <kbd>F11</kbd>, or you can use HUD (only on 12.04+): press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and type `cheese`.

You will see the menu of Cheese. Type `full` then click on `Cheese > Full screen`.